# Using CSS for 3 column layout, left/right variable size, mid fluid

Tags: html, css, layout

I need 3 column layout, first and 3rd column sizes are variable because there will be image or some variable length text(or another image) but i need middle to fill the rest space with background image, something like this if it would work like i imagine :

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left-vp">
   <img src="~/Content/images/vp1.png" />
</div>
<div class="mid-vp">

</div>
<div class="right-vp">
<p>
    //some text here or another img
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .left-vp {
    float: left;
 }

 .mid-vp {
    height: 2px;
    background: #FFFFFF url("images/dot.png") repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
 }
 .right-vp {
    float: right;
 }
```

Is something like this possible with CSS?

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear with example let me know if helps thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the markup, and don't mind making changes, you can use table block styles to accomplish this. It's the only way I know of which will handle all scenarios and resizing.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="col col1">
      <div class="nowrap">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2 fill center">
      <div class="nowrap">Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      <div class="nowrap">Column 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { width: 100%; }
.container { display: table; }
.container > div { display: table-row; }
.container > div > div { display: table-cell; }
.container > div > div { padding: .5em; }

.container .nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }
.container .fill { width: 100%; }
.container .center { text-align: center; }

.col1 { background: red; }
.col2 { background: blue; }
.col3 { background: green; }
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/Vxc3n/1/

A few things to keep in mind:

1. If your first and 3rd columns contain text, you will need to wrap them in a DIV which has the white-space: no-wrap CSS style
2. If you have more than 1 fill column, ensure the width total = 100% (eg, 2 columns, use 50%)
3. You won't be able to shrink the columns beyond the minimum required width

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="right"></div>
   <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{width:100%;}
#left{float:left;width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: gray;}
#right{float:right;width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
#center{margin:0 auto;width:100%; height:100px;  background-color: blue;}
```

in action -> http://jsfiddle.net/5xfR9/39/

Comment: actually this is the problem http://jsfiddle.net/5xfR9/44/ when i dont know size - i cant specify size of either left or right because there is image which can be variable sized, just look at that right column, is below center column what is not expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your actual requirements are for that central column but if it's just to contain a background as in the question could you not move the background styles to the container itself?

As an expansion on Eriks' jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xfR9/46/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div id="left">some text</div>
  <div id="right">some text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{ width:100%; background-color: blue; }
#left{ float:left; height: 100px; background-color: red; }
#right{ float:right; height: 100px; background-color: green; }


.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

I've added a clearfix class to make sure the container actually *contains* the columns so that the background can show through (this is the clearfix class from a version of HTML5 Boilerplate).

Comment: i thought about this too, but the problem is if u apply margin on left image or right image it wont be reflected as background image would overflow these margins, and if right side will be text div the background image will be visible too

Answer (score 0):

You just need to play around with min-width and max-width properties until you get what you want. And it seems to work easiest when you give the columns a max-width as a percentage of the body or a wrap.

Here is a working example i put together:

http://jsfiddle.net/76Ep3/1/

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">LEFT content...</div>
     <div id="center">CENTER content...</div>      
    <div id="right">Right content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}

body, html{
    height:100%;
}

#wrap {
    min-width:390px;
    height:100%;
}

#left{
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:37%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
}

#center {
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:20%;
    background-color:red;    
    height:100%;
}

#right {
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:37%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
}
```